# Case is not creating through Community User

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforcedx, case

I am have created the Lighting page for Create case for a community user, Through "Community Plus" License User case is creating, but when we are creating through  "Community Users" case is created but It is giving this error on my Community

[image]
and It will not proceed to after case creation page, Can anyone have an idea about this error. Is there any permission related issue?

Comment: Can you check if there is any case assignment setup or apex code changing the case owner to a queue or another user, when the community user is creating the case ? if the case owner is changed via such mechanisms then the community user may no longer have access to the case and this can explain the error

Comment: Yes, we are assigning a queue using the case assignment rule. But in Customer Community Plus User this condition is working fine. So is there any way to set the rules as same as for Community User so that, Community user can also access the case information.

Comment: Could you first clarify what is the user license for the other type of user which you called "Community user" ?